# I am trying to automate command execution in ttyd ? any leads here

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, automation

I was assuming ttyd opens a websocket connection
Then by using websocket library i am trying to send simple message like "hi" and expecting some output which i am not getting .
Any one has done automation related to ttyd please help

I was assuming ttyd opens a websocket connection
Then by using websocket library i am trying to send simple message like "hi" and expecting some output which i am not getting .